# Make new rows and columns in a data frame by parsing a string in a specific column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with about 8000 entries that has the structure:

```
df <- structure(list(user = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                     string = c("Text A [111]; Text B [121]; Text C [131]", 
                                "Text A [211]; Text D [212]", "Text D [311, 321]"), 
                     var1 = c(58, 39, 21)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

As you can see the `string` column is comprised of several "texts" associated with some number in brackets and separated by a semicolon.

I would like to somehow parse this column to create a new data frame where each "text" element is on it's own row, and the number within the square brackets is in a new column. All this while maintaining the other columns. In essence the new data frame should look like:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
     "user" = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
     "string" = c("Text A", "Text B", "Text C", "Text A", "Text D", "Text D"),
     "value" = c("111", "121", "131", "211", "212", "311, 322"),
     "var1" = c(58, 58, 58, 39, 39, 21)
)
```

I really appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)


df %>%
  separate_rows(string, sep = ";\\s*") %>%
  mutate(value = str_extract(string, "\\[(.*?)\\]"),
         string = str_replace(string, "\\s*\\[.*?\\]", ""),
         value = str_replace_all(value, "\\[|\\]", "")
         )
```

```
user string    value var1
1    A Text A      111   58
2    A Text B      121   58
3    A Text C      131   58
4    B Text A      211   39
5    B Text D      212   39
6    C Text D 311, 322   21
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you kindly! I couldn't get the base R solution below working, but I'm sure there was some substitution I am missing going from the made up data frame to the actual one, and the tidyr approach above was not working because I didn't account for specific cases in my MWE. This solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
library(tidyr)
df |> 
  separate_longer_delim(string, "; ") |> 
  separate_wider_regex(string, c(string = "Text \\D+", " \\[", value = ".*", "\\]")) |> 
  separate_longer_delim(value, ", ")

#   user string value var1
# 1    A Text A   111   58
# 2    A Text B   121   58
# 3    A Text C   131   58
# 4    B Text A   211   39
# 5    B Text D   212   39
# 6    C Text D   311   21
# 7    C Text D   321   21
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @Maël . I think I'm running into a problem because not every string in the `string` column contains the format "Text E [111]" format. For example, I added a row, `df <- rbind(df, list(user="D", string="Text E", var1=82))` and this subsequently breaks your solution with the same error I get running on the full data frame:  "Expected each value of `string` to match the pattern, the whole pattern, and nothing but the pattern."

Answer (score 0):

In base R we can do

```
> strsplit(s, r'{;\s|\s(?=\[)}', perl=TRUE) |> 
+   lapply(matrix, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) |> lapply(gsub, pat=r'{\[|\]}', rep='') |> 
+   Map(data.frame, user=df$user, string=_, var1=df$var1) |> do.call(what='rbind')
    user string.1 string.2 var1
A.1    A   Text A      111   58
A.2    A   Text B      121   58
A.3    A   Text C      131   58
B.1    B   Text A      211   39
B.2    B   Text D      212   39
C      C   Text D 311, 321   21
```